# Probability of drawing two cards

Tags: probability

If I have five different cards, valued at 0 - 4 with a probability of drawing each card at 1/4 (for values 0, 1 and 2), 3/20 (for value 3) and 1/10 (for value 4). I draw 2 cards at random without replacing it after I draw it, how do I calculate the probability of drawing two specific cards (e.g. values 0 and 0, 3 and 2, 1 and 4, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unless you know how the weights for the second card are affected by extracting the first.  IE: the conditional probabilities.

$$\mathsf P(\{X_1,X_2\}=\{x,y\}) ~=~ \mathsf P(X_1=x)~\mathsf P(X_2=y\mid X_1=x)+\mathsf P(X_1=y)~\mathsf P(X_2=x\mid X_1=y)$$

Comment: So there are 5 cards each of value 0, 1 and 2 and there are 3 of value 3 and 2 of value 4.

Comment: Then if those *individual* cards have no selection bias: $\mathsf P(\{X_1,X_2\}=\{3,4\}) = \dfrac{2!\times(3\times 2)}{20\times 19}$ and so forth.  ( Also $\mathsf P(X_1=4, X_2=4) = \dfrac{2}{20\times 19}$ )

Comment: I've used your equation, except I'm getting a total of 117%. [This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EO9f4dj4NqoNwX89CRpDrcr8TGmNIXqNt4yaYD8JqOE/edit?usp=sharing) is my results, have I done something wrong?

Comment: @PeterZhu Yes.  You don't multiply by $2!$ when the cards have the same face value.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\{X_1,X_2\}{=}\{0\}) =&~ \dfrac{5\times 4}{20\times 19}\\[1ex]\mathsf P(\{X_1,X_2\}{=}\{0,1\}) =&~ \dfrac{2!\times(5\times 5)}{20\times 19}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I'm curious to why you don't multiply by 2! when there the cards are of the same value?

Comment: @PeterZhu Because when drawing two identical values it doesn't matter which order you draw them; where as when drawing different face values there are two orderings in which they can be drawn.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\textsf{both }0)=&~\mathsf P(X_1=0\cap X_2=0)\\[1ex]\mathsf P(\textsf{draw }\{0,1\})=&~\mathsf P(X_1=0\cap X_2=1)+\mathsf P(X_1=1\cap X_2=0)\end{align}$$